# How to pass different commands in tkinter based on user input

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm starting to learn python and thought it would be a good idea to also learn tkinter. What I'm doing is a program that takes 3 numbers as user input and calculate something with them, printing something as a result.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack()
e3 = Entry(root)
e3.pack()
l = Label(root)
l.pack()

def my_function(a,b,c):
    if some condition:
        (calculations)
        l.config(text="Option1")
    else:
        (calculations)
        l.config(text="Option2")

b = Button(root, text="Result", command= lambda: my_function(float(e1.get()),float(e2.get()),float(e3.get())))
```

My question is, how can I set the button to print an error message in case the inputs are not numbers? When I try to do this inside the function, I get

```
ValueError: cannot convert string to float
```

I managed to make it work despite still printing an error in the shell by using

```
def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func
def checknumber():
    if not isinstance(e1.get(),float) or not ...(same for the others):
        l.config(text="Only numbers")
b = Button(root, text="Result", command= combine_funcs(checknumber, lambda: my_function(float(e1.get()),float(e2.get()),float(e3.get()))))
```

Is there an easier way that do not give me an error? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `try-except` instruction:

```
try:
    # your code
    b = Button(root, text="Result", command= lambda: my_function(float(e1.get()),float(e2.get()),float(e3.get())))

except ValueError:
    # if it catches the exception  ValueError
    b = Button(root, text="Only numbers")
```

More about [Exception handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: Yes, but how do I implement it? I tried wrapping the button call in the `try-except` (which is where the error is), but it doesn't work, keep telling me that `b = Button(root, text="Result", command=  lambda: my_function(float(e1.get()),float(e2.get()),float(e3.get())))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: a` If I do it in a separate part of the code, it gives me the same error.

Comment: Code to test in `try` block,  Code if the test fails in `except` block

Comment: In my mind this should work `try: b = Button(root, text="Result", command= lambda: my_function(float(e1.get()),float(e2.get()),float(e3.get()))) except ValueError: l.config(text="Only numbers")`, but it doesn't, and I get exactly a ValueError for that lambda function when I enter a string in one of the entries

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. If i put the entire code (apart from functions definitions) inside the `try` block, it doesn't work. What I did before (my second comment) didn't work either. What exactly should go inside the `try` block?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Still doesn't catch the exception